# MS Word Web Add-In complex search string fails

Tags: javascript, add-in

I'm trying to compose a complex search in a JavaScript Add-In to find a set of strings in a word document and convert them to links. I've got it working, except that the search string doesn't seem to want to let me combine special characters and wildcards the way I need to.

The strings in the document always start with the same three letter prefix followed by a blank, followed by 1 to 10  alphanumeric characters followed by a period, followed again by another 1 to 10 alphanumeric characters. The string is terminated by either a blank space or any non-alphanumeric character.

I've tried to take it slowly, starting with specific common cases. ('XYZ ^#^#^$.^#^#^#'); for instance and working up to ('XYZ 81[A-Z].123', { matchWildcards: true }); or even [0-z] which gets all alphanumerics but also punctuation. However, when I try to create a more complex search string, like a regular expression string, I just get a general exception.

For instance, I tried ('XYZ 81[^#^$].123', { matchWildcards: true }); and had hopes of something more like [^#^$]{1,10} to match 1 to 10 alphanumeric characters, but every time I start mixing up wildcards and special characters, or even more than one wildcard, it fails.

Here's my code, running in Script Lab on Word for simplicity of trying out combinations. My main add-in is composed in VS 2022:

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  console.log("Code running.");
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const body = context.document.body;
    var searchResults;
    context.load(body, "text");
    return context
      .sync()
      .then(function() {
        searchResults = body.search('XYZ [^#^$]{1,10}.[^#^$]{1,10}', { matchWildcards: true });
        //('XYZ ^#^#^#.^#^#^#', { matchWildcards: true});
        searchResults.load("text");
        context.load(searchResults, "text");
      })
      .then(context.sync)
      .then(function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
          var sItem = searchResults.items[i].text;
          var sSubOneTwo = sItem.slice(4);
          var sSubArray = sSubOneTwo.split(".");
          var sSubOne = sSubArray[0];
          var sSubTwo = sSubArray[1];
          var sLink = "http://www.MyLinks.com/Sub/XYZ/" + sSubOne + "/" + sSubTwo+ "/";
          var sAnchorTag = '<a href="' + sLink + '" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">' + sItem + "</a> ";
          searchResults.items[i].insertHtml(sAnchorTag, "replace");
        }
      })
      .then(context.sync);
    //showNotification("Debug Info", "Code Ran");
    

    await context.sync();
  });
  console.log("Code ran.");
}

/**function showNotification(header, content) {
  $("#notification-header").text(header);
  $("#notification-body").text(content);
} */

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem, once I figured out that the two white spaces I was dealing with were a regular char 32 whitespace and a char 160 *non-breaking white space*. Normal manual find-and-replace in word finds both of these when you simply enter a white space manually, but programmatically a white space in a search string is interpreted strictly as char 32... which is why doing a manual find-and replace for a whitespace character solved the issue, it found both types of white space and replaced them with char 32.

So... I can do a straight wildcard search using:

```
Body.search('XYZ[' + String.fromCharCode(32, 160) + '][0-9a-zA-Z]{1,10}.[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{1,10}', { matchWildcards: true });
```

... and find all cases. I still feel like it's a little ridiculous that I can't just throw in a ^w when matchWildcards is set to true, but I'll create a new post for that.